# How to save div content (img) on server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing a web application where users can crop images.Users must be able to email the URL so others can view the cropped image. This means every cropped image must be stored on the server so that the URL will never die. The portion of my HTML that contains the cropped image is:

```
<div class="contain" id="myDiv">
    <img src="" id="croppedImage">
</div>
```

The cropping function works fine and it is written in JavaScript. I am using PHP to parse through the DOM, extract the image and save it on the server but it is not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//img[id="croppedImage"]');

$my_server_img = $divContent;
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($my_server_img);
$path = 'images_saved/';
imagejpeg($img, $path);
?>
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Charlotte Sure, when I check the 'images_saved' directory it is still empty. I expect to see the cropped image stored there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your code and checking out the functions you are using I looked at this part: `$xpath->query('//img[id="croppedImage"]');` and compared to http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php you can see that the function returns a `DOMNodeList` element (even if nothing is found it will return the object with no children.. You are then taking this object and passing it to `imagecreatefromjpeg($filename)` that accepts a string as $filename, not an object. Also your xpath selector is wrong, you need to prefix `id` with `@` like so: `$xpath->query('//img[@id="croppedImage"]');`

So here is some code that will grab an `<img />` element off a page by it's `id` and then download the URL of the `src` attribute and save it. You will want to make sure that the src of the image you are downloading is a `jpg` file otherwise `imagecreatefromjpeg()` will fail. You could use CURL or another method to download images (so you can get png images as well) but that is out of the scope of this answer.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('
    <html>
        <img src="http://images.freepicturesweb.com/img1/18/02/13.jpg" id="croppedImage2"/>
        <img src="http://images.freepicturesweb.com/img1/18/02/14.jpg" id="croppedImage3"/>
    </html>
');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$imageElements = $xpath->query('//img[@id="croppedImage2"]');

// make sure $imageElements isn't empty
if($imageElements->length) {
    // grab first item in list (should only be one)
    /** @var DOMElement $imageElement */
    $imageElement = $imageElements->item(0);
    // get the src attribute off the <img>
    $src = $imageElement->getAttribute('src');
    // download and create image resource based off $src
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    // save image with random name to current directory
    $filename =  __DIR__.'/'.base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36).'.jpg';
    imagejpeg($img, $filename);
    echo "File saved to: ".$filename;
}
```

Should also be noted that you were assigning a variable to a variable. Things can get messy quick by doing this. If you want a variable to be called something else just set the name when you initialize it instead of assigning it to another variable with the name you want (I'm guessing this is just something you left over after trying some code out, but still worth mentioning).

Comment: This answered lots of questions for me. Thanks a lot. This actually clarified a lot of my doubts.

Comment: Of course! Just remember that php.net is a godsend when you need any information on a function.